# $f(x)=|\cos x|+|\sin(2-x)|$ at which of the following point $f$ is not differentiable?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

$f(x)=|\cos x|+|\sin(2-x)|$ at which of the following point $f$ is not differentiable?

1.$\{(2n+1){\pi\over2}\}$

2.$\{n\pi\}$

3.$\{{n\pi\over 2}\}$

4.$\{n\pi+2\}$

in all cases $n\in\mathbb{Z}$

well, is there any easy trick to solve this type of probelem in an competitive examination? Do I need to pick $\pi \over 2$ from $1$ and cheked that $f$ is differentiable and same trick from each set? in some what I am lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function isn't differentiable where it has sharp corners since the tangent line at that point is not well-defined. In this case, it fails to be differentiable when $\cos(x)$ and $\sin(2-x)$ change sign since the absolute value of a function has a sharp cusp when its argument changes sign.

[image]

Comment: could you explain how did you draw the graph? what is the analysis behind the graph?

Answer (score 1):

> $f(x)=|x|$ then $f'(x)=\text{sign}{(x)}$

Here $f(x)=|\cos x|+|\sin(2-x)|$

Using the result mentioned at the beginning we get

$f'(x)=\text{sign}{(\cos x)}\times (-\sin{x})+\text{sign}{(\sin(2-x))}\times \cos{\left(2-x\right)}$

Now all you have to do is to check the continuity of the function $f'(x)$ at the point mentioned .

**Note**:
 $g(x)=\text{sign}{(t(x))}=\begin{cases}{ -1 \quad \text{if } f(x)<0\\+1 \quad \text{if } f(x)>0 } \end{cases}$ .

Answer (score -1):

Hint: The function $ g(y)=|y|$ isn't differentiable at $ y=0$, and therefore, $ g(\cos x)+g(\sin(2-x))$ isn't differentiable when it's arguments are $0$, meaning, when $ \cos x=0$ or when $ \sin (2-x)=0$

Comment: "isn't differentiable when it's arguments are 0, meaning" Not necessarily true  . Counter-example $f(x)=|x^2|$

Comment: @boywholived It has written $g(y) = |y|$ it is not $g(y) = |y^2|$.

Comment: @srijan . The conclusion is wrong.